# memory leak in QQmlApplicationEngine

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

while I was developing an qml application I found following error in memory analysis

```
32 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 3,755 of 9,076
  in main in /home/m/Qt5.9.1/Examples/Qt-5.9.1/location/minimal_map/main.cpp:64
  1: operator new(unsigned long) in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
  2: QQmlEnginePrivate::QQmlEnginePrivate(QQmlEngine*) in /home/m/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5.9.1
  3: QQmlApplicationEnginePrivate::QQmlApplicationEnginePrivate(QQmlEngine*) in /home/m/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5.9.1
  4: QQmlApplicationEngine::QQmlApplicationEngine(QObject*) in /home/m/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5.9.1
  5: main in /home/m/Qt5.9.1/Examples/Qt-5.9.1/location/minimal_map/main.cpp:64
```

Here is my `main.cpp` class and the error refers to this line  `QQmlApplicationEngine engine;` I could not figure out how to solve it? It does not give me any clue how to free its memory.

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "gcppoint_.h"
#include "gcppointobject.h"
#include "georefobject_.h"
#include <qdebug.h>
#include <qquickitem.h>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QObject>
#include "gcppointobject.h"
#include "gcppoint_.h"
#include "georefobject_.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);


    //qmlRegisterType<gcppointobject>("gcppointobject", 1, 0, "gcppointobject");
    qmlRegisterType<georefobject_>("georefobject_", 1, 0, "Georefobject");
    qmlRegisterType<gcppoint_>("gcppoint_", 1, 0, "Gcppoint");


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.addImportPath("/home/m/Qt5.9.1/Examples/Qt-5.9.1/location/minimal_map/imports");

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: According to the output you shared it's a possible leak, and it's in the Qt library  files. So the most probable cause would be that `QQmlEnginePrivate` class some how traverse the pointer and then use an interior pointer to `deallocate` original pointer, `Valgrind` doesn't know about this and as the original pointer changed, it will mark it as possible leak.

Comment: "possibly lost" doesn't mean "definitely lost", even thou qt is very far from perfect, 32 bytes is no big deal if it is a one time per application session leak

Comment: "possibly lost" generally means either a) you are using some sort of memory manager which suballocates blocks allocated with malloc in which case this is really a "still in use" or b) there is some stray random pointer pointing somewhere inside a definite leak.